# How stay final state of animation CSS and remove animation property?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, opacity

I want to stay with final properties of css animation, but remove animation property itself, exmeple:

```
@keyframes('foo')
{
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

at the begining :

```
.my_element
{
   opacity: 0;
}
```

I apply animation by Javascript, so I got :

```
.my_element
{
   opacity: 0;
}

element.style
{
   animation: foo 1s forwards; #with opacity: 1; at the end.
}
```

And now I need clean up :

```
.my_element
{
   opacity: 0;
}

element.style 
{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `animation-play-state`?

Comment: is this your real animation ?  else you can freeze a transition so it takes ages to go back to initial value  http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wGEXer (hover the invisible p and move mouse out )

Answer (score 1):

This does exactly what you're asking. On `animationEnd`, the `cleanUp` function is passed an object containing the class to remove after the animation, the property to replace on the element, and the property value to replace on the element. Check out the DOM before and after clicking button the and you'll see that this works properly.

```js
var el      = document.querySelector(".my_element"),
    cleanUp = function(data) {
      el.classList.remove(data.remove);
      el.style[data.prop] = data.val;
    },
    startAnimation = function() {
      el.classList.add("animate");
    };

el.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
  var cleanup_data = {
    remove: "animate",
    prop: "opacity",
    val: 1
  };
  
  cleanUp(cleanup_data);
});
```

```css
@keyframes foo {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to { opacity: 1; }
}

.animate {
  animation: foo 3s forwards;
}

.my_element {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="my_element">some text</div>
<button onclick="startAnimation()">Start Animation</button>
```

Comment: yes but you have to define final properties at the hand in javascript. If I use other animation, this will not work. I need generic method.

Comment: I will make the function generic for you.

Comment: Ok, I wait to see how you do that^^

Comment: Unfortunately, making this generic would require your HTML to contain little hints about property names inside the keyframe animation (which isn't ideal). For transitions, we can tell which properties transitioned using `event.originalEvent.propertyName`. There is no such access for animations, there no way to automatically run the clean up part of your question. I tried my best, but it's just not a thing that can happen. This is as far as I got. http://codepen.io/antibland/pen/QNVxBB